# Posting still running after nearly 4.5 days

Tags: arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase, arccatalog, versioning, reconcile

I haven't reconciled and posted in about a month. I added a large amount of new data to our database on many different feature classes over this time. When I reconciled I believe there were around 8000 conflicts and I resolved those in the edit versions favor. This all worked fine. The reconcile is done but when I go to post to Default in Arcmap my window freezes. I am currently running the Reconcile Versions tool in ArcCatalog on another work station. It started running on the Oct 14 2016 and is still running now on Oct 18 2016. I have the task manager window open on the work station and it shows the CPU usage going from 0 or 1 up to 30 or 40 and in between in 5 second blips every 20-30 seconds. I believe that the post is still running but I am concerned about how long this is taking.

Comment: What is a "large amount"?

Comment: Around 15 new survey plans. Each including sanitary lines and services, Water Mains and Lines, Storm Sewers. Road information as well as sidewalks, cubs, Man holes and Catch basins. I work for a Municipality and all of these were capital projects so everything in the area that could be changed, upgraded or replaced was.

Comment: How many edited features though?  4.5 Days does sound odd, but it may all come down to the number of new or edited features.  Also are other people modifying the data (even in different versions)?

Comment: There is one other person editing on a different version. I'm not sure of the number of new and edited features but I would spend all day editing the base. It is a very large amount of edits. Over 8 thousand.

Comment: Large amount is relative.  We've been known to edit 150000+ in a day, which can make the Reconcile/Post process drag, but usually even that's under 10 minutes.  It sounds like it may have stalled.

Comment: Do you have Archiving enabled, and are your features part of complex dataset (like Network, Geometric network, Topology)?

Comment: In the end I had to call ESRI Tech support. They helped me out and narrowed the error to our topology and roads. I had to remove the feature data-set and run the check and fix geometry tools. After everything was fixed just had to put it back in and version the feature data-set and we were right as rain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esri Tech Support ended up running me through what I had to do to fix the problem. While working on my extensive edits to our Database an error had occurred in our 'Roads' and Road Topology. To fix the issue Tech Support had me make a copy of 'Roads' and delete it out of my version. I then deleted my version of Road Topology. I ran the check and fix geometry tools on my version of 'Roads' and replaced 'Roads' in our default version with my fixed version to keep my edits. I then set up the road topology in default again. Once all of this was done I ran a reconcile and post and deleted and remade my version. This ended up fixing the issue.